# Why HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath is different on different servers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

In asp.net mvc applications I have a code like this:

```
var p = HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
if (p.EndsWith("Login.aspx")) return;
```

This code is executed on each request in `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method. The problem, is that on one computer p is `~/Login.aspx` and `~/Login.aspx/LoginUser` on the other. The request was made to `~/Login.aspx/LoginUser`. Why the behavior is different ?

Answer (score 0):

It gets the *virtual path* of the application *root* and makes it relative by using the tilde (~) notation. It does not says anything about the parameters of the path that you passed throught.

If you look at the begining of the returned string, it is the same. I'm pretty sure that the URL in each request is different, with and without `LoginUser`, so the complete returned string seems different base on that, althought, for the function, they are the same.